# Find users created during a specific hour range (any day)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For fun, I'd like to see the set of users (in a Rails database) who were created during a specific hour range (2AM - 5AM to be specific), but on any day. They all have the typical created_at field. I think I know how to extract the hour from this field for one user, and then see if it falls in a range--but how I do do this for all of them? Should I just loop through them? (Even as I write it, that sounds naive).

Comment: Try this, User.where(created_at: Time.parse("2pm")..Time.parse("5pm"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of Sontyas answer is the easy solution in rails.
I would however move that part to it's own place inside your class to separate your code from the framework a bit more.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# ...
  def self.get_users_created_between(start_time, end_time)
    User.where("TIME(created_at) BETWEEN TIME(?) AND TIME(?)", start_time, end_time)
  end
# ...
end
```

And use it like this:

```
irb> User.get_users_created_between(Time.parse("2pm"), Time.parse("5pm"))
```

This provides you with a couple of benefits:

1. You can reuse it all over your code without ever having to worry about the syntax of the where or time ranges.
2. If for some weird reason rails decides to change the interface for this, you only need to edit one method and not code in a thousand places all over your project.
3. You can easily move this piece of code out of the user.rb if you feel that user.rb gets to big. Maybe to some dedicated finder or query class. Or to something like a [repository pattern](http://hawkins.io/2013/10/implementing_the_repository_pattern/).

PS: Time functions may vary between different DBMS like MySQL, Postgresql, MSSQL etc. I don't know, if there is generic way to do this. This answer is for MySQL.

Comment: Does this actually work? `Time.parse("2pm")` returns `2015-02-09 14:00:00` on my system, so your code returns users created between 2pm and 5pm *today*.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't read that it is supposed to work on any day. I'll change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Milan--this is a good, clean, and (like you say) DRY answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
User.where(created_at: Time.parse("2pm")..Time.parse("5pm"))
```

Or something like this

```
User.select { |user| user.created_at.hour.between?(2, 5) }
```

Comment: Change this `#each` to `#select` and it will be perfect.

Comment: @hakcho -  Thanks for the correction, I didn't tried the code

Comment: Check the documentation for [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) again, not what I meant.

Comment: I think you no need to mention `all` before `select` as it will go and fetch whole db. And one more thing not even need to initialized array as it return in Array only

Comment: @GaganGami `#select` is a ruby method, nothing to do with Rails or ActiveRecord.

Comment: @Sontya just this - `User.select { |user| user.created_at.hour.between?(2, 5) } `. I would advise you to read more about pure Ruby and check `Enumerable`, `Hash` and `Array` documentation.

Comment: @hakcho : Yes I completely agreed and aware about it. But was saying d way he used in code. It return the same result without `all`

Comment: Does your first line actually work? Time.parse("2pm") returns 2015-02-09 14:00:00 on my system, so your code returns users created between 2pm and 5pm *today*.

Comment: @Stefan - sorry but I did't have tested it

Answer (score 1):

To return users that where created between two hours on any given day, use this:

```
User.where('HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?', 2, 5)
```

Please note that `HOUR(created_at)` only works for MySQL. The syntax in Postgresql is `extract(hour from timestamp created_at)` and `strftime('%H' created_at)` in SQLite.

Comment: Same works for time: `TIME(created_at) BETWEEN "14:00" AND "17:00"`